# Two definitions of vectors

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

Abstractly, are vectors better defined as elements of a vector space or rank 1 tensors. I've heard of vectors in the context of tensors as generalizations of scalars, vectors, and matrices. However, since you could have a vector space of matrices, matrices can be considered vectors sometimes. These definitions don't seem to compile since one separates the ideas.

Comment: The word "vector" is overloaded and means different things in different contexts. Hopefully the context will make it clear which definition is being used. Whenever we are working with some vector space $V$, the elements of $V$ might be called "vectors" in that context.

Comment: To define a vector as a rank 1 tensor leads to the question...what is a tensor?

Comment: I think now looking back that while any tensor can be considered a vector, it is not necessarily and only a tensor of rank one is guaranteed to be a vector or element of a module more generally.

Comment: So I'd say a vector is an element of a vector space in the most abstract sense, as I asked

Comment: Strictly speaking, matrices are not rank 2 tensors. Rank 2 tensors can be *represented* by matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe type (1,0) tensor is better than rank 1 tensor for describing vectors. Co-vectors are also rank 1 tensors. By definition, a type (m,n) tensor is an element of $\underbrace{V\otimes\cdots\otimes V}_m\otimes \underbrace{V^\ast\otimes\cdots V^\ast}_n.$ Saying something is a type (1,0) tensor is equivalent to saying it is a member of a vector space. By tradition, a rank 0 tensor just represents a member of the field that the vector space $V$ is over. For clarity sake, it might be "better" to just say that vectors are members are vector spaces and tensors are a type of equivalence class over vector and dual spaces. $V\otimes W=F\!\left(V\times W\right)/\sim$ where $F$ is the free vector space and $\sim$ is the equivalence relation that defines the tensor product. When combined with scaling and addition rules, it has a basis of $\left[v,w\right]$ for $v\in V, w\in W$ usually denoted $v\otimes w.$